# pdf to jpg with ImageMagick

Tags: php, imagemagick

Installed on local server imagemagick, but do not understand how to convert ALL pages of pdf file into a single image jpg. And whether it is even possible.

Without specifying the page number only converts the first page

```
    $im = new imagick( "libs/pdf/files/$Jfile" );
    // convert to jpg
    $im->setImageColorspace(255);
    $im->setCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
    $im->setCompressionQuality(60);
    $im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
    //resize
    $im->resizeImage(385, 500, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);  
    //write image on server
    $im->writeImage("libs/pdf/files/$JPGfile");
    $im->clear();
    $im->destroy();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options...

**Option 1**

To make each page of the PDF come out as a separate JPEG, change the 3rd last line from:

```
$im->writeImage("libs/pdf/files/$JPGfile");
```

to something like:

```
$im->writeImages("z%03d.jpg",false);
```

**Option 2**

To make all pages of the PDF come out in a long list, change where the comment says "write image on server" to the following:

```
// Write on server
$im->resetIterator();
$appended = $im->appendImages(true);
$appended->writeImage("appended.jpg");
```

Change `true` to `false` depending on whether you want a tall list of images or a wide one.